# QuantLib: Garch help needed

Tags: c++, quantlib

I'm playing around with QuantLib in a simple Windows Command Prompt application and can't get the Garch function work.

I'm not sure I've understood how to use the Garch11 object and it could be a consequence of this why my program doesn't work. I've not been able to find any examples of how to use it either. The documentation is also (IMO) vague too. I appreciate any help or clues on how to use it.

What I want to do it pass a method a vector of prices (minimum 4 as this is the minimum for the garch model object) and return the volatility for this series as a vector or double, don't mind.

There are two ways of constructing my object, one via the Greeks and the other via Self Optimisation. Both methods will be tested in my application.

Currently, when I run the code I get differing outputs each time I run the code e.g.:

```
D:\Users\ypx7647\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\GarchTest\Release>GarchTest.exe
iQuotes size = 4
ts size = 4
GarchByGreeks iTs size = 4
_alpha = 0.000000 _beta = 0.000000 _omega = 0.000000
oTs size = 4
tsOut size = 4
oGarch[0] = 121.182504
oGarch[1] = 121.182504
oGarch[2] = 121.182504
oGarch[3] = 121.182504
oGarch size = 4
og size = 4

D:\Users\ypx7647\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\GarchTest\Release>GarchTest.exe
iQuotes size = 4
ts size = 4
GarchByGreeks iTs size = 4
_alpha = 0.000000 _beta = 0.000000 _omega = 0.000000
oTs size = 4
tsOut size = 4
oGarch[0] = 11003897096.575457
oGarch[1] = 11000266346.069284
oGarch[2] = 10995727907.936573
oGarch[3] = 10998450970.816200
oGarch size = 4
og size = 4
```

After debugging my code, I see that the Garch11 constructor passing using the Greeks does not register the same values that are passed. This one problem.

Next the returned object returns the same number of values as the input object. I don't want this and need to return just the volatility. This is the second problem.

The other problem that I'm experiencing is that I am unable to pass the size_t parameters of the EndCriteria argument as variables and this just crashes the app. To my knowledge all the parameters are configured as size_t parameters and therefore, no conversion or casting.

What do I need to change to get my code to work (I'm not an expert in C++)?

Here's my code (including debug lines):

GarchTest.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CGarch.h"

int main()
{
//  CGarch* Garch = new CGarch(Method::SelfOptimisation);
CGarch* Garch = new CGarch();

std::vector<double> p, og;

p.push_back(121.230000);
p.push_back(121.190000);
p.push_back(121.140000);
p.push_back(121.170000);

Garch->GarchOnArray(p,og);

std::cout << "og size = " << std::to_string(og.size()) << std::endl;

delete Garch;
return 0;
}
```

`
CGarch.h

```
#include <ql/quantlib.hpp>

#define _MD

enum Method {
    Greeks,
    SelfOptimisation
};

enum OptimizationMethodType {
    simplex,
    levenbergMarquardt,
    levenbergMarquardt2,
    conjugateGradient,
    conjugateGradient_goldstein,
    steepestDescent,
    steepestDescent_goldstein,
    bfgs,
    bfgs_goldstein
};

enum Model {
    LevenbergMarquardt,
    Simplex
};

enum Mode {
    MomentMatchingGuess,   /*!< The initial guess is a moment
                           matching estimates for
                           mean(r2), acf(0), and acf(1). */
    GammaGuess,            /*!< The initial guess is an
                           estimate of gamma based on the
                           property:
                           acf(i+1) = gamma*acf(i) for i > 1. */
    BestOfTwo,             /*!< The best of the two above modes */
    DoubleOptimization     /*!< Double optimization */
};

class CGarch
{
private:
    int GarchByGreeks(const QuantLib::TimeSeries<QuantLib::Volatility> &iTs, QuantLib::TimeSeries<QuantLib::Volatility> &oTs);
    int GarchByOptimisation(const QuantLib::TimeSeries<QuantLib::Volatility> &iTs, QuantLib::TimeSeries<QuantLib::Volatility> &oTs);

protected:
    int         _method;
    int         _model;
    int         _mode;
    std::size_t _maxIterations;
    std::size_t _maxStationaryStateInterations;
    double      _rootEpsilon;
    double      _functionEpsilon;
    double      _gradientEpsilon;
    double      _omega;
    double      _beta;
    double      _alpha;

public:
    CGarch();
    CGarch(Method pMethod);
    CGarch(double pOmega, double pBeta, double pAlpha);
    CGarch(Model pModel, Mode pMode, std::size_t pMaxIterations, std::size_t pMaxStationaryStateIterations, double pRootEpsilon, double pFunctionEpsilon, double pGradientNormEpsilon);
    ~CGarch();
    int GarchOnArray(const std::vector<double> &iPrices, std::vector<double> &oGarch);
};
```

CGarch.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CGarch.h"
#include <vector>
#include <ql/auto_link.hpp>
#include <ql/models/volatility/garch.hpp>
//#include <ql/math/optimization/simplex.hpp>
#include <ql/math/optimization/levenbergmarquardt.hpp>

using namespace QuantLib;

CGarch::CGarch()
{
    _method = Method::Greeks;

    CGarch::CGarch(0.0, 0.1, 0.3);
}

CGarch::CGarch(Method pMethod)
{
    _method = pMethod;

    switch (pMethod) {
    case Method::Greeks:           CGarch::CGarch(); break;
    case Method::SelfOptimisation: CGarch::CGarch(Model::LevenbergMarquardt, Mode::BestOfTwo, 20, 3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0); break;
    }
}

CGarch::CGarch(double pOmega, double pBeta, double pAlpha)
{
    _method = Method::Greeks;
    _model = 0;
    _mode = 0;
    _maxIterations = 0;
    _maxStationaryStateInterations = 0;
    _rootEpsilon = 0.0;
    _functionEpsilon = 0.0;
    _gradientEpsilon = 0.0;
    _omega = pOmega;
    _beta = pBeta;
    _alpha = pAlpha;
}

CGarch::CGarch(Model pModel, Mode pMode, std::size_t pMaxIterations, std::size_t pMaxStationaryStateIterations, double pRootEpsilon, double pFunctionEpsilon, double pGradientNormEpsilon)
{
    _method = Method::SelfOptimisation;
    _model = pModel;
    _mode = pMode;;
    _maxIterations = pMaxIterations;
    _maxStationaryStateInterations = pMaxStationaryStateIterations;
    _rootEpsilon = pRootEpsilon;
    _functionEpsilon = pFunctionEpsilon;
    _gradientEpsilon = pGradientNormEpsilon;
    _omega = 0.0;
    _beta = 0.0;
    _alpha = 0.0;

    std::cout << "SelfOptimisation _maxIterations = " << std::to_string((unsigned int)_maxIterations) << " _maxStationaryStateInterations = " << std::to_string((unsigned int)_maxStationaryStateInterations) << " _rootEpsilon = " << std::to_string(_rootEpsilon) << " _functionEpsilon = " << std::to_string(_functionEpsilon) << " _gradientEpsilon = " << std::to_string(_gradientEpsilon) << std::endl;
}

CGarch::~CGarch()
{
}

int CGarch::GarchByGreeks(const TimeSeries<Volatility> &iTs, TimeSeries<Volatility> &oTs)
{
    std::cout << "GarchByGreeks iTs size = " << std::to_string(iTs.size()) << std::endl;

    if (iTs.empty()) {
//      QL_FAIL("ERROR: input array (iTs) is empty");
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "_alpha = " << std::to_string(_alpha) << " _beta = " << std::to_string(_beta) << " _omega = " << std::to_string(_omega) << std::endl;

    Garch11* g11 = new Garch11(_alpha, _beta, _omega);
//  Garch11 g11(_alpha, _beta, _omega);
    /*
    if (g11 == NULL) {
    QL_FAIL("FATAL; Unable to instantiate Garch11 object");
    return -1;
    }
    */
    g11->calibrate(iTs);
    oTs = g11->calculate(iTs);

    std::cout << "oTs size = " << std::to_string(oTs.size()) << std::endl;

    delete g11;

    return 0;
}

int CGarch::GarchByOptimisation(const TimeSeries<Volatility> &iTs, TimeSeries<Volatility> &oTs)
{
    std::cout << "GarchByOptimisation iTs size = " << std::to_string(iTs.size()) << std::endl;

    if (iTs.empty()) {
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "GarchByOptimisation _maxIterations = " << std::to_string(_maxIterations) << " _maxStationaryStateInterations = " << std::to_string(_maxStationaryStateInterations) << " _rootEpsilon = " << std::to_string(_rootEpsilon) << " _functionEpsilon = " << std::to_string(_functionEpsilon) << " _gradientEpsilon = " << std::to_string(_gradientEpsilon) << std::endl;

    Garch11* g11 = new Garch11(iTs, Garch11::MomentMatchingGuess);

    if (g11 == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "FATAL: Failed to create g11 object " << std::endl;
        return -2;
    }

    std::cout << "Here 1" << std::endl;

    QuantLib::LevenbergMarquardt om;
    std::cout << "Here 2" << std::endl;
    g11->calibrate(iTs, om, EndCriteria(200, 3, _rootEpsilon, _functionEpsilon, _gradientEpsilon));
    std::cout << "Here 3" << std::endl;
    g11->calibrate(iTs);
    std::cout << "Here 4" << std::endl;
    oTs = g11->calculate(iTs);

    std::cout << "Here 5" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "alpha = " << std::to_string(g11->alpha()) << " beta = " << std::to_string(g11->beta()) << " omega = " << std::to_string(g11->omega()) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "oTs size = " << std::to_string(oTs.size()) << std::endl;

    delete g11;

    return 0;
}

int CGarch::GarchOnArray(const std::vector<double> &iQuotes, std::vector<double> &oGarch)
{
    oGarch.clear();

    std::cout << "iQuotes size = " << std::to_string(iQuotes.size()) << std::endl;

    if (iQuotes.empty()) {
//      QL_FAIL("ERROR: input array (ts) is empty");
        return -1;
    }

    if (iQuotes.size() < 4) {
//      QL_FAIL("ERROR: minimum (3) individual prices not present in ts array");
        return -2;
    }

    Date ds(7, July, 1962);
    TimeSeries<Volatility> ts(ds, iQuotes.begin(), iQuotes.end()), tsOut;

    std::cout << "ts size = " << std::to_string(ts.size()) << std::endl;

    if (_method == Method::SelfOptimisation)
    {
        if (GarchByOptimisation(ts, tsOut) < 0)
            return -3;
    }
    else {
        if (GarchByGreeks(ts, tsOut) < 0)
            return -4;
    }

//  QL_ASSERT(false, "tsOut size = " + std::to_string(tsOut.size()));
    std::cout << "tsOut size = " << std::to_string(tsOut.size()) << std::endl;

//  tsOut.find(ds + ts.size());
    oGarch = tsOut.values();

    for (int i = 0; i < oGarch.size(); i++)
        std::cout << "oGarch[" << std::to_string(i) << "] = " << std::to_string(oGarch.at(i)) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "oGarch size = " << std::to_string(oGarch.size()) << std::endl;
//  QL_ASSERT(false, "oGarch size = " + std::to_string(oGarch.size()));

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These types of inconsistent behaviors typically point towards having uninitialized variables in the code.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your code and find where your results differ from expected.

Comment: @Frank Yes, this did cross my mind however, I'm not sure if my application of the QuantLib calls are correct (as it is based on the test-suite code and docs) and I couldn't see any that wasn't uninitialised. But fundamentally you are probably right.

Comment: @hnefatl Valid point.I always forget about debuggers and their usefulness.

Answer (score 1):

Code such as

```
CGarch::CGarch()
{
    _method = Method::Greeks;

    CGarch::CGarch(0.0, 0.1, 0.3);
}
```

is not valid. If you want to delegate to another constructor, in C++11 and later you can write instead

```
CGarch::CGarch() : CGarch(0.0, 0.1, 0.3)
{
    _method = Method::Greeks;
}
```

I don't know what your version does (that depends on what your compiler decides it to mean) but I suspect that it's just creating a separate temporary and that your data members are not initialized.

Comment: Thanks for you input. I didn't know this. However, given that you haven't commented about the QuantLib specific code I have to assume that is it correct. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: I have never used Garch myself, so I'd have to find some time to look at your code. What happens if you do the correction above?